# boost uint128_t with varying behaviors

Tags: c++, boost, g++, clang++

I have the following program:

```
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    boost::multiprecision::uint128_t res;
    inet_pton(AF_INET6, "2001:db8:8714:3a90::12", &res);
    cout<<res<<endl;
}
```

Depending on the compiler I used, I got 3 different behaviors:

clang++-3.8

```
23926103924128485722661168748298043680
```

g++-5.3.0

```
23926103924128485722661168748298043680
```

clang++-3.6

```
3087860000
```

g++-6.1.0

```
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/config.hpp:61:0,
             from /usr/local/include/boost/cstdint.hpp:36,
             from /usr/local/include/boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp:11,
             from main.cpp:4:
/usr/local/include/boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp:181:4: error: right operand of shift expression '(1u << 63u)' is >= than the precision of the left operand [-fpermissive]
BOOST_STATIC_CONSTANT(limb_type, sign_bit_mask = 1u << (limb_bits - 1));
^
/usr/local/include/boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp:404:4: error: right operand of shift expression '(1u << 63u)' is >= than the precision of the left operand [-fpermissive]
BOOST_STATIC_CONSTANT(limb_type, sign_bit_mask = 1u << (limb_bits - 1));
^
/usr/local/include/boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp:556:4: error: right operand of shift expression '(1u << 63u)' is >= than the precision of the left operand [-fpermissive]
BOOST_STATIC_CONSTANT(limb_type, sign_bit_mask = 1u << (limb_bits - 1));
^
```

`c++14` was enabled in all cases. Could somebody please explain why this is happening? The expected behavior of course was the first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

inet_pton takes a void*

You're passing the address of a non-primitive with undocumented layout.

The result is implementation-defined at best. Possibly Undefined Behaviour.